# SwiftUI NavigationLink with Button

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have the following code, and the view changes clicking anywhere in the circular button.  However, the `self.user.day += 1` action only executes if I click directly on the button text.  This is very curious behavior to me, being new to Swift & SwiftUI in particular.

```
NavigationLink(destination: NewsView(), tag: 1, selection: $selection){
    Button(action: {self.selection = 1; self.user.day += 1}){
        Text("News").font(.body)
    }
    .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.96, green: 0.96, blue: 0.47))
    .background(Color.black)
    .cornerRadius(90)
}
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI will not detect taps in blank areas, no matter how big your button is, this excludes the `NavigationLink`.

A simple way, in your case is just to set the frame to the text instead of the button like so

```swift
Button(action: { print("tapped"); self.selection = 1 }) {
    Text("News").font(.body)
        .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
}
    //.frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.96, green: 0.96, blue: 0.47))
    .background(Color.black)
    .cornerRadius(90)
```

Comment: perfect.  Thank you!